# Colocar item lado a lado com border redond CSS

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web ,e gostaria que meus icones `i class="fa fa-user"` e `i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"` ficasse lado a lado e queria  que ficasse um circulo em volta de cada um mas não estou conseguindo.

```
        <div class="col-6 col-md-4">

            <ul class="menu_2">
                <div class="user"><li><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Entre/Cadastre-se<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></li></div>
                <div class="carrinho"> <li><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">Carrinho</i></li></div>

            </ul>
        </div>

     .menu_2{
padding: 10px;
font-size: 10pt;  
margin-top: 40px;

}

 .user{
margin-right: 30px;
font-size: 13pt;
border-radius: 1px solid ;
}

 .carrinho{
margin-left: 240px;

}
```

Olha como está os icons

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode usar `float: left;` no CSS onde vc quer colocar lado a lado:

Mais ou menos assim:

```
.user{
margin-right: 30px;
font-size: 13pt;
border-radius: 1px solid ;
float: left;
}
```

e Border Radius para criar o circulo

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Espero q ajude

Answer (score 0):

Quanto a colocar um circulo no ícone você pode usar Stacked Icons do próprio font-awesome, fica assim:

`<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>`

Mais exemplos aqui: http://fontawesome.io/examples/

Agora colocar um na frente do outro tem diversas formas, mas como você provavelmente está usando bootstrap e está usando ul, pode usar esta classe do bootstrap

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



 <div class="col-6 col-md-4">
    <ul class="menu_2 list-inline">
        <li class="user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Entre/Cadastre-se<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></li>
        <li class="carrinho"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart">Carrinho</i></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Isso você encontra aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#type-lists

Comment: Ahh, já ia esquecendo, escrevendo html deve é interessante sempre se atentar a semântica do html, por isso removi a div envolvendo os li, e a classe você coloca diretamente no li se precisar fazer alguma coisa com ela